# How to add Customer Phone Number and Company to Authorize.net ARB Create Subscription API

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I am using **Authorize.net** API **Create Subscription API (ARB)** using this API reference -
[API Document](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#recurring-billing-create-a-subscription)

Everything is working fine.

Just I want to add phoneNumber and company in customer billing information. Its also given in API reference but I am unable to send in subscription object.

[image]

[image]
For checking code you can check in above share API Document the PHP Code.

Its really appreciate if someone help me out in this.

Comment: Show the code you are using and what isn't working for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest you can include company under billTo block, the request also can take an optional customer block, you may include phoneNumber under the customer block. For more detail visit the API reference and check the **request field description** section under the request in question. (Api Ref.: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#recurring-billing-create-a-subscription).

[ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest billTo.company | customer.phoneNumber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPJQC.png)